# Postfix master.pid ExecStartPre with exit status 255

Tags: postfix, redhat, systemd, service, selinux

When I restart the Postfix daemon on my Rockylinux server, It happen an `restorecon` error who don't avoid the starting of the service but still an error :

```
 ● postfix.service - Postfix Mail Transport Agent
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/postfix.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2022-07-26 19:02:20 CEST; 30min ago
  Process: 2277 ExecStop=/usr/sbin/postfix stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 2300 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/postfix start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 2298 ExecStartPre=/usr/libexec/postfix/chroot-update (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 2295 ExecStartPre=/usr/libexec/postfix/aliasesdb (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 2292 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/restorecon -R /var/spool/postfix/pid/master.pid (code=exited, status=255)
 Main PID: 2368 (master)
    Tasks: 3 (limit: 11346)
   Memory: 4.4M
   CGroup: /system.slice/postfix.service
           ├─2368 /usr/libexec/postfix/master -w
           ├─2369 pickup -l -t unix -u
           └─2370 qmgr -l -t unix -u

   systemd[1]: Starting Postfix Mail Transport Agent...
   restorecon[2292]: /usr/sbin/restorecon: lstat(/var/spool/postfix/pid/master.pid) failed: No such file or directory
   postfix/master[2368]: daemon started -- version 3.5.8, configuration /etc/postfix
   systemd[1]: Started Postfix Mail Transport Agent.
```

I don't understand why he can't find the master.pid even though he is here in */var/spool/postfix/pid/* when the service is up.

Thanks per advance for provided help

Answer (score 1):

If postfix was not running prior to it being started in a later step, at the time this command is called, **the file may not exist yet**. `ExecStartPre=` is used to specify commands systemd shall call **before** `ExecStart=`, so your verification of the file existing *after* that point does not test for the same thing.

Ask the distributor/maintainer of that unit file, this does not look intentional to me.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a misstep in the systemd unit file coupled with selinux, as if selinux is disabled (completely, not just switched to permissive mode) the error is gone. I eventually solved it for myself by adding a `touch` into the unit file before the `restorecon` is issued.

First I copied the systemd unit file into `/etc/systemd/system/` where customized unit files should be put:

`cp /usr/lib/systemd/system/postfix.service /etc/systemd/system/`

then edited `/etc/systemd/system/postfix.service` and added a line containing

`ExecStartPre=-/usr/bin/touch /var/spool/postfix/pid/master.pid`

before the line containing `restorecon`. So my unit file looks like:

```
[Unit]
Description=Postfix Mail Transport Agent
After=syslog.target network.target
Conflicts=sendmail.service exim.service

[Service]
Type=forking
PIDFile=/var/spool/postfix/pid/master.pid
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/sysconfig/network
PrivateTmp=true
CapabilityBoundingSet=~ CAP_NET_ADMIN CAP_SYS_ADMIN CAP_SYS_BOOT 
CAP_SYS_MODULE
ProtectSystem=true
PrivateDevices=true
ExecStartPre=-/usr/bin/touch /var/spool/postfix/pid/master.pid
ExecStartPre=-/usr/sbin/restorecon -R /var/spool/postfix/pid/master.pid
ExecStartPre=-/usr/libexec/postfix/aliasesdb
ExecStartPre=-/usr/libexec/postfix/chroot-update
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/postfix start
ExecReload=/usr/sbin/postfix reload
ExecStop=/usr/sbin/postfix stop

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

After that issue a systemd reload with `systemctl daemon-reload` so it reads the new/modified postfix unit file.

Now stopping&starting/restarting postfix does not produce the error anymore (the postfix process was actually running anyway, only the `restorecon` had an exit code not equal to 0).

Comment: thank you - confirming this fixed the issue on RHEL8

Answer (score 1):

This has been fixed by removing "**/master.pid**" filename from /usr/lib/systemd/system/postfix.service

**Change:** ExecStartPre=-/usr/sbin/restorecon -R /var/spool/postfix/pid`/master.pid`

**To:** ExecStartPre=-/usr/sbin/restorecon -R /var/spool/postfix/pid

Source: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=2162659#c3